# список объектов. Есть ли такое вообще?

Tags: python, классы, list, объекты, список

изучаю python вот уже неделю. изучил основы, объекты, классы. Пробую все это закрепить в виде проекта (ну или что то в этом роде). Делаю консольную игру. Суть проста: выбираете героя, ходите (цифрами) в разные места, убиваете монстров, покупаете воинов, предметы и др.

***Проблема в следующем:***
не могу реализовать инвентарь. У меня там должны храниться объекты, такие как объекты класса еда (хлеб, морковь, эль...), оружие (меч, лук, кинжал...) и т. п.. Можно ли реализовать список объектов? Может, список заменить чем-либо еще?
Просто мне нужно будет иногда выводить содержимое инвентаря, который

*Простите за неграмотно сформулированную задачу и "воду" в тексте.*

```
***Все. Благодарю всех кто откликнулся. Решение нашел. Создаю объекты а затем просто помещаю их в инвентарь
bread = UsingItem('хлеб', 10, 40, 4)
water = UsingItem('вода', 5, 10, 6)
#имя, регенерация хп, цена, количество
inventory = [bread, water]***
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? `items = [Bread(...), Water(...), Ale(...), ...]`

Comment: Изучение лучше начинать с учебника. А то вы ещё ходить не научились, а уже стометровку бежать пытаетесь.

Comment: В `python` практически все является объектом, и числа и строки, и даже классы и функции, и все это можно хранить в списке.

Comment: MaxU, а как указать принадлежность к нужному классу?

Comment: @АйтиЛанселот, например `isinstance(items[0], Bread)`

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите сделать список объектов - так в чём проблема?
Пример:

```
backpack = []
backpack.append(UsingItem('хлеб', 10, 40, 4))
backpack.append(UsingItem('вода', 5, 10, 6))
```

`backpack` - список объектов `UsingItem`

Также можно создать собственный класс на основе класса `list`:

```
class Backpack(list):
    pass

backpack = Backpack()
backpack.append(UsingItem('хлеб', 10, 40, 4))
backpack.append(UsingItem('вода', 5, 10, 6))
```

На этот раз `backpack` является объектом класса `Backpack`, который, в свою очередь, является подклассом(subclass) класса `list` и не переопределяет ровным счётом ничего, то есть, грубо говоря, мы просто дали имя `Backpack` классу `list`(данный пример более "хороший")

Почитайте про [списки](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html), а также советую посмотреть YouTube каналы или почитать книги по Python прежде чем спрашивать тут такие вопросы :)